# Observable In AgGrid:CellRenderer

Tags: angular, observable, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to add some data from my backend to the AGGrid cell renderer component but it is not reading the observable data

Here's what I've tried so far

1. Call the service directly from within the cellRenderer component
2. Call the service in the data grid and pass the value as a cellRendererParams

```js
// My Grid Options
gridOptions: {
  columnTypes: {
    "actionColumn": {
     cellRenderer: 'actionColumnRenderer',
     cellRendererParams: {
        canEdit$: this.userInfo.getUserRole() // Returns a Observable<boolean>
     }
  }
}
```

```html
//Inside ActionColumnRenderer
  <div *ngIf="(canEdit$|async)></div>
```

```js
// Calling in the service in the actionRenderer directly
agInit(params:any){
  this.params = params;
  this.canEdit$ = this.userInfo.getUserRole();
}
```

There's nothing wrong with the observable as I am able to access it in all my other components(even inside the data grid component)

Any ideas?

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: I'd love to give an example but I'm not sure how much it would help since it's just some basic AGGrid cellRendering components. Added it anyways

Comment: Instead of passing observable as params, try passing it's value after getting it inside subscription. Initialize `gridOptions` inside subscription part of `getUserRole`

Comment: gridOptions needs to be initialised as soon as the component is created. This is because it is used by ag-grid and once initialised I’m unable to dynamically change the gridOptions properties.

Comment: that is correct, so delay initializing your ag-grid till you get it. ex. `<ag-grid-angular *ngIf="gridOptions" gridOptions="gridOptions"....></ag-grid-angular>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use Angular inside of a cell renderer, you should set the `cellRendererFramework` property, not the `cellRenderer` property. For example:

```
customColumn: {
  cellRendererFramework: MyCellComponent
}
```

Then you will be able to use your service inside the cell component, and the observable will work. See this simple example of an angular cell renderer component that uses an observable: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-cell-renderer

Documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/angular/components/#registering-framework-components

Comment: I tried to use cellRendererFramework but still got the same result. Unable to subscribe to any obseravable data from within the cellRenderer

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameter as a function like this:

```
canEdit$: () => this.userInfo.getUserRole()
```

then inside the CellRenderer:

```
// Calling in the service in the actionRenderer directly
agInit(params:any){
  this.params = params;
  this.canEdit$ = canEdit$;
}
```

template:

```
//Inside ActionColumnRenderer
<div *ngIf="(canEdit$()|async)></div>
```